# String to double with precision

Tags: java, string, double, precision

I do have a String that is read from the file with the value: 38.739793110376837

When i convert this value to double using:

```
double.parseDouble("38.739793110376837");
```

I get the result: 38.73979311037684

How can i have the original value in a double variable?

I don't want to use BigDecimal data type.

Comment: You want to avoid rounding errors but you don't want to use `BigDecimal`? Uhm?

Comment: I simply wanna get the same value in a double.

Comment: I'll just leave [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) here

Comment: `double` has a limited size, 64-bit, this means you can only pack so much information into it.  If you use BigDecimal, it can be almost any size which is why it doesn't lose precision.

Comment: The result you get is the nearest value `double` can represent. It is already doing the best it can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can i have the original value in a double variable?

You can't. The closest `double` to your original value is *exactly* 38.739793110376837148578488267958164215087890625

That's being converted to "38.73979311037684" because that's the shortest value which uniquely identifies that `double` value. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-):

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double. That is, suppose that x is the exact mathematical value represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for a finite nonzero argument d. Then d must be the double value nearest to x; or if two double values are equally close to x, then d must be one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of d must be 0.

If you want to retain *exactly* your original value, you should be using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: It's proof that you just can't represent that value exactly in a `double`, since my example doesn't deal with another data type. (OP might be thinking it's `parseDouble`'s fault.)

Comment: Oh, you're completely correct. Do you think I should remove my comment?

Comment: @2rs2ts: Yup - you delete all yours, and I'll delete all mine too.